# When should we draw Mirror Extension to show Line of Symmetry

Tags: reflection, mirror-symmetry

In the attached image, the mirror extension is drawn to show the line of symmetry to solve this question. My doubt is that under which condition, we should draw the line of symmetry. [image]

Comment: When an exam question asks you.

Comment: Also they are required to extend in both directions in order to show the *line* of symmetry. Extending in one direction only is a *ray*.

Comment: A better solution is to reflect the observer about the mirror rather than P, Q, and R. Less work that way.